# Python if and loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

In Python looping and or/if

I've been using a Long process but limited codes.But codes must be in short process but Infinite

print("Press[A] to add a fruit")

print("Press[B] to edit a fruit list")

['apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'orange']

Enter your choice:A

Enter a fruit to be added: apple
A fruit is already exist in record no.1

my codes has limitation like

if fruit in choice 1 print a fruit is already exist in record no.1

if fruit in slot choice 2  print a fruit is already exist in record no.2

......
What is the short process for Infinite code in determining in what record sequence exist in list.

Comment: instead of list use set to store fruits and use while loop to run this process till you want

Answer (score 1):

Please explain your doubt clearly, based on my understanding you require a infinite loop with some options provided to the user and based on the user input, the operations had to be done.

The code can be

```
#...
while True:
    print("Press[A] to add a fruit")
    print("Press[B] to edit a fruit list")
    print("Press[C] to exit")
    choice = input("Enter your choice:")
    # Space to do your logic
    if choice == 'C':
        break
    #....
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the problem but if your problem is not adding existing items to a list then you can use a `set` to add fruit since all the values in it will be unique

Example:

```
Fruits = set()
Fruits.add('Apple')
Fruits.add('Orange')
Fruits.add('Apple')
Fruits.add('Banana')
print(Fruit)
```

Output:

```
{'Orange', 'Apple', 'Banana'}
```